# Where to submit a Bug-Report regarding a Bluetooth issue?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mouse, bluetooth, launchpad, bug-reporting

I have found a bug at my UbuntuTouch phone but I dont know where so submit...

Of course I searched on launchpad, but I cannot find the right place where to put the bug report. Here is my bug description:

First I connect a bluetooth mouse to my UbuntuPhone. Then everything works pretty fine until I use the 'backward' key on the mouse, which is normally used to navigate in web browser. If I press this 'backward' key, the UbuntuPhone just crashes and restarts immediatly.

I have not much experience in unsing launchpad. So can anyone tell me where to submit this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+filebug?no_redirect

Also, check out this page:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Avengers

It's like a map to submit and look for bugs in Ubuntu-Touch.

Comment: Thanks! The BugReport goes here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1546994

Comment: Glad you reported it. Looks nasty...